# In my keyboard, is there a way to advance or backup the insertion point?

Tags: cyanogenmod, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Using the keyboard in Cyanogenmod, sometimes while typing in a sentence, I see a point where I would like to make an edit.  Presently, I do this by touching with my finger where I want the insertion point to be, however, it is hard to get the exact location, often I miss it by one or two characters.  In such cases, instead of trying again and again until I get it right (which is most difficult to position right at the beginning of the text) is there a way to advance the cursor forward of backwards by one position somehow?  In other words, on a computer, I would press the forward or backward arrow keys to move one position, is there something like that in the keyboard?

Comment: When you touch with your finger do you not get a blue indicator "tab" just below where the cursor has been placed? It is usually then fairly easy to drag this "tab" (and corresponding cursor) a couple of characters to the correct position.

Comment: @w3d Yes, the blue arrow can be dragged around.  I think that qualifies as the answer, so why don't you post it?

Comment: @w3d : it is *NOT* fairly easy if i want to place the cursor right in the middle of a "ii", which is exactly 1 pixel wide... -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, when you tap some text to set the insertion point you should get a blue indicator "tab" just below where the cursor has been placed. It is usually then fairly easy to drag this "tab" (and corresponding cursor) a couple of characters to the correct position.

Unfortunately, unlike some other keyboards, the stock Android keyboard does not have arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the stock keyboard but in Swiftkey and Kii keyboard(a wonderful and free alternative to stock keyboard and Swiftkey) you and enable arrow keys, ie → ← ↑ ↓. I think this might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can install an alternate keyboard to gain this functionality. I put Hackers Keyboard (free in Play Store) on my Nexus 10 and have it configured with arrow keys. Ctrl-C/X/V also work (for cut & paste shortcuts).